# In clause with multirelationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to query - For *n* number of `Organization` in the `IN` clause, to fetch all the Entity who works for the organizatin and Entity who are getting benefits from the organization. I have a query like this :

```
match(e1:Entity)<-[r1:ORG_BENEFITS]-(o:Organization)<-[r2:WORKS_FOR_ORGANIZATION]-(e2:Entity) 
where o.id IN ['11','22','33','44','55'] 
return o.id as org, collect(DISTINCT e1) as gettingBenefits, collect(DISTINCT e2) as worksForOrg
```

The problem here is, i am getting the details for only one id from the `IN` clause.
I tested the `IN` clause with one relationship and it is working fine. But with two relationships, it is not working. It's only giving the output for the first occurrence of the id from the `IN` clause.

Comment: Do BOTH r1 and r2 exist for each organisation in the array?

Comment: Is it possible that you have the direction of the relationships wrong? Have you tried performing the test without the directions on the relationships? e.g. `match(e1:Entity)-[r1:ORG_BENEFITS]-(o:Organization)-[r2:WORKS_FOR_ORGANIZATION]-(e2:Entity)`

Comment: @frant.hartm Yes Both r1 and r2 exists for each organization in the array.

Comment: @DaveBennett Direction of relationship is right, tthough I tried without direction as well.

Comment: @shaw.ram So if you remove e.g. the r2, e2 part of match then it correctly returns n rows (for n size array) with correct data? Do you have some sample data?

Comment: IN clause is working fine with query like - match(o:Organization)<-[r2:WORKS_FOR_ORGANIZATION]-(e2:Entity) where o.id IN ['11','22','33','44','55'] return o.id as org,collect(DISTINCT e2) as worksForOrg,  match(e1:Entity)<-[r1:ORG_BENEFITS]-(o:Organization) where o.id IN ['11','22','33','44','55'] return o.id as org, collect(DISTINCT e1) as gettingBenefits. I have to prepare the sample data. I will put once ready.

Comment: Do your `Organization` nodes have unique `id` values? For example, check if this query always has a `1` in the `c` column: `MATCH (o:Organization)
WHERE o.id IN ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55']
RETURN o.id, COUNT(*) AS c;`

Comment: Yes, Organization have unique Id.

Comment: I found the issue for my problem. The relationship was not available for the Id, i was searching for in IN clause. It's my mistake and i was suspecting that IN clause is not working properly. IN clause is actually working tested with Id for which the relationship is exists.